# How can i make world environment nodes connect with signals across and between scenes to change atmosphere when entering area nodes

Tags: godot, gdscript

wont work bidirectionally to make world environment scenes to the levels link with atmosphere change, here is the code

`

```
extends Spatial
#RedFell.gd
export onready var Forest = $"/root/GlobalWorldEnvironment"
export onready var RedFell = $"/root/RedFellEnvironment"

signal player_entered_forest

func _ready():
    var player_desert = get_tree().get_root().find_node("RedFell", true, false)
    player_desert.connect("player_entered_forest",self, "_player_entered_desert")
    
func _on_DesertArea_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        Forest.environment = RedFell.environment
        emit_signal("player_entered_forest")
        print(body)

func _on_DesertArea_body_exited(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        pass

func _player_entered_desert():
    print("Player entered Desert")
    Forest.environment = RedFell.environment
```

`currently this changes the forest level to the desert atmosphere world environment, but cannot make it bidirectional with this`

```
extends Spatial
##Forest.gd
export onready var Forest = $"/root/GlobalWorldEnvironment"
export onready var RedFell = $"/root/RedFellEnvironment"

signal player_entered_desert

func _ready():
    var player_desert = get_tree().get_root().find_node("RedFell", true, false)
    player_desert.connect("player_entered_desert",self, "_player_entered_forest")

func _on_ForestArea_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        RedFell.environment = Forest.environment
        emit_signal("player_entered_desert")

func _on_ForestArea_body_exited(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        pass
        
func _player_entered_forest():
    print("Player entered Desert")
    Forest.environment = RedFell.environment
```

`
I've been trying to get this work but it doesn't change back to the forest when walking back into the forest level

Comment: also to note, i've put the world environments into separate scenes

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are losing the reference to the environment in your attempt to swap them.

Store the environments to resource files, and `load` or `preload` the one you want instead:

```
$"/root/GlobalWorldEnvironment".environment = preload("res://path/to/forest_enviroment.tres")
```

Comment: I really dont understand what you mean, i saved the World Environment as a resoruce saving it as .tres but idk how you would implement it